# Setting annotation for a @test method at run time using testngListners

Tags: java, testng, testng-annotation-test

I am working on allure reports using testng and have a very basic method like below.

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Hello this is a description for allure report")
public void method1(){
  System.out.println("Hi i am from method1");
}
```

here in the above code, @DisplayName is from allure report. Now what i am trying to achieve is to set the DisplayName at runtime using TestngListners.

I looked ITextResult and ITestContext, but as per my knowledge it does not have support for this.

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Junit launcher, you can get display names simply by iterating over Test Plan.

The code for display names is as :

```
testPlan.getRoots ()
            .forEach (testIdentifier -> testPlan.getChildren (testIdentifier).
                    forEach (testIdentifier1 -> testPlan.getChildren (testIdentifier1).
                            forEach (testIdentifier2 -> testCaseList.add (testIdentifier2.getDisplayName ()))));
```

Comment: No i required support for adding annotation for a method at run time